# methods that return cross product of two 3xN arrays (e.g. time-dependent vectors)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two vectors evaluated at say 10,000 points as two `[3, 10000]` arrays. Reading the definitions for `np.cross` and `np.einsum` I don't understand how to use them without a loop to get the cross product here.

This is what I do now, just hard-wired arrays. Can either of those, or anything else within the `numpy` or `scipy` universe do this as fast? I'm thinking that it would be nicer to use something standard like `np.cross` or `np.einsum` even if it's the same speed as my method, but I don't see how without looping.

```
def cross_these(a, b):

    c0 = a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1]
    c1 = a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2]
    c2 = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]

    return np.vstack((c0, c1, c2))
```

Comment: Do you want to take the cross product of pairs of rows? So take N independent cross products?

Comment: I want to do exactly what I have written in the script. `a` and `b` are 3xN arrays. Unless I misunderstand, I think the answer is therefore yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [optional keyword arguments to `np.cross`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html) that specify which axes of the input (and possibly output) arrays correspond to Cartesian coordinates, and you're done:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3,5)
b = np.random.rand(3,5)
c = np.cross(a, b, axisa=0, axisb=0, axisc=0)

# check if each row is equal to the simple cross-product
all(np.allclose(np.cross(a,b,axisa=0,axisb=0)[k],
                np.cross(a[:,k],b[:,k])) for k in range(a.shape[1]))
```

Comment: OK, I think I'll need `axisc=0` also to recover the original shape, but this is just exactly what I needed. Thank you - and love the hat! (or a transpose, or transpose in the arguments, or.... Anyway I've got it.)

Comment: Haha, thanks:) Sorry about `axisc`, you're right. I'm not sure about the internals of `np.cross`, but it *might* matter in performance if you transpose your arrays so that the final dimension is the Cartesian one (especially if you have the freedom to do this for your whole code, rather than transposing back and forth near `np.cross`). Might be worth a try if speed matters (worst case is that the original is faster).

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but note that Divakar's answer might be  a bit or a lot faster depending on the size of the problem. Really, it depends on the size.

Comment: I may in fact use that, or I may not (easy to have an error in the index at some point in time and then oops) But I've actually asked for an *existing method* in the question as written. Sometimes having an existing method actually written "np.cross" that reminds me and everyone else reading it of exactly what it is, and that can't get muddled is more important than speed.

Comment: Just a quick note, for a quick test on 3x10000 (that's 1E+04) on my laptop, my script is 200 μs, and all numpy permutations (using axis parameters or transpose views) as well as the one-liner by @Divakar are about 240 μs (100 repeats of 100 loops). In other words everything is almost the same within the array-size sweet spot of 10k, except the ugliest one (mine) is a tad faster. Milage may vary.

Comment: `np.cross` uses the last axis as the working one (with length 2 or 3).  So it will `roll` the specified axis to last if needed.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, that's good to know:) So if I understand correctly, transposing the input/output leads to the same performance, but refactoring the code to have those indices as last might matter.

Comment: `np.cross` has been optimized for that axis-is-last case - including the careful use of `out` parameters to reduce the use of temporary variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
d0 = np.array([[1,2,0],[2,0,1]]) # Scaling values
d1 = np.array([[2,0,1],[1,2,0]])
out = a[d0[0]]*b[d1[0]] - a[d0[1]]*b[d1[1]]
```

As one-liner -

```
a[[1,2,0]]*b[[2,0,1]] - a[[2,0,1]]*b[[1,2,0]]
```

Comment: I'm curious - besides being nifty, is writing it this way of any benefit if I'm not knowingly/explicitly vectorizing the calculation (something I don't know how to do yet). [As noted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242891/#comment69686915_41243001) a quick test doesn't show any performance difference no matter how I do it (on my laptop).

Comment: @uhoh Ah yes, its because `a[[1,2,0]]`, etc. we are making copies. In your original approach you are using one index at one time, so its just a view. So, you are seeing the benefits of using `views` there. See here for more info : [`Colon notation vs using indices for slicing`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41207648/3293881).